# symfony Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: symfony, security

I can not access the admin page from my symfony project.

If I visit XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/admin I get:

```
Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

However going to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/security/login gives me the login page.

What am I doing wrong?

```
security:

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
          users:
              admin:
                  password: XXX
                  roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
      algorithm: bcrypt



firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/admin
        anonymous: ~
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
        form_login:
            login_path: security_login
            check_path: security_login
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: userRedirectAction
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /blog

access_control:
 # require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
  - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Answer (score 6):

I think under your secured area firewall you need to specify an authentication type such as `http_basic: ~`

Answer (score 0):

secured area should be:

```
secured_area:
    pattern: ^/blog/admin
```

It's working now

Answer (score 0):

If you want just test if it does work, you may change your user's role in the path,  an delete the anonymous option

```
  - { path: ^/admin, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

It should be work